# How to efficiently do data transformation in R?

Tags: r

My research generates raw data from titrations that needs a substantial number of calculations before I get the numbers in a form that I can analyze.  Most of these calculations are relatively simple unit conversions etc...  Typically I create a spreadsheet in Excel to perform all of these calculations and then only import the finalized values into R for analysis.

I would like to move all of the data processing into R so that the data are all in one place therefore easier to work with.

My attempts at doing these calculations in R has resulted in the creation of lots of objects that are the result of the calculations, such as:

```
mlTitr <- endTitr - beginTitr
val <- mlTitr * std - blnk
conVal <- val * convFac
.
.
.
ad nausium
```

I then stitch all the new objects together into a data frame but this approach seems inefficient.

Is there a better way to do this in R?

(or am I barking up the wrong tree and this is really the task that a spreadsheets were created for)?

Comment: Doing the calculations in R instead of Excel should be preferable because that makes the calculations both _documented_ and _reproducible_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I prefer R to Excel for cleaning data.  It is certainly possible to do heavy data cleaning in Excel, but I find the mixture of the spreadsheet, Excel equations, and Visual Basic to be tedious and less productive than R.

When I need to repeatedly clean data, I usually write an R function, which only needs to be written once, can be re-run tomorrow or a year from now, is reproducible, and can easily be given to collaborators or passed on to the next generation. I also find it easier to find bugs in an R script compared to hunting through Excel cell equations.

You did not specify what your data look like, but consider these very unrealistic titration data as an example:

```
## Example data
n <- 100
beginTitr <- rnorm(n, mean = 10, sd = 1)
endTitr <- beginTitr - rnorm(n, mean = 2, sd = 1)

# Variables
titrData <- data.frame(beginTitr, endTitr)

# Constants
std <- 0.00500
blnk <- 1e-5
convFac <- 2
```

Then, you could write a function to clean the data, such as:

```
## Function to clean data
cleanData <- function(x, std, blnk, convFac)
{
    mlTitr <- x$endTitr - x$beginTitr
    val <- mlTitr * std - blnk
    conVal <- val * convFac

    out <- data.frame(x, mlTitr, std, blnk, val, convFac, conVal)

    return(out)
}
```

And then you could call the function on your data whenever needed:

```
## Clean data
titrDataClean <- cleanData(x = titrData, std = std, blnk = blnk, convFac = convFac)

## View data
head(titrDataClean)
```

You still have to code all your calculations *ad nauseum*, but you only have to code them *ad nauseum* once.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I don't have a lot of experience with writing functions, so your example is really helpful.